# Django rest framework permission by custom role

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I using Django Rest Framework and I have custom User model where is column **Role** and **Hash**

Model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    Role = models.CharField()
    Hash = models.CharField()
```

Serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'Role', 'Hash','is_staff')
```

View.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

this working fine! And my question is possible create view which show fields according by **Role**?

For example... If user with *admin* role login then see everything..

```
fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'Role', 'Hash','is_staff')
```

But if login user with role for example *mamager* then he see just this.

```
fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'Role','is_staff')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create a view that shows fields according to the user's role. You can do this by creating a custom serializer for each role and using it in the view.

Try this:

```py
class AdminUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'Role', 'Hash','is_staff')

class ManagerUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'Role','is_staff')

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.Role == 'admin':
            return AdminUserSerializer
        elif self.request.user.Role == 'manager':
            return ManagerUserSerializer
        else:
            return UserSerializer
```

Here we've defined two custom serializers - `AdminUserSerializer` and `ManagerUserSerializer` - that show different fields based on the user's role. We've also defined a [`get_serializer_class`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself)
method in the `UserViewSet` that returns the appropriate serializer based on the user's role.